# Ionic 3 virtual scroll only displays a small part of the items

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm having trouble with the Ionic 3.3.0 virtual scroll due to the fact that I have a ~360 items array and it only displays the first 15 on the phone. Has anyone encountered this issue?

P.S.: The virtual scroll list is in a container that has 35% of the screen height. Don't know if this has an effect on the issue or not...

```
this.friendsList = [{name: 'John'},...,{name: 'Zed'}];

<div class="friends-list__container">
  <ion-list [virtualScroll]="friendsList">
    <ion-item *virtualItem="let friend">
      {{friend.name}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Afer investigating the issue, I've left a comment on bug #11798 (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/11798/)  from the ionic platform: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/11798/#issuecomment-304463189 . Hope they will come with a solution.

Answer (score 4):

After researching the issue, it seems that the solution was to **add an extra DIV wrapper** around the virtual scroll list:

```
<div class="friends-list__container">
  <div> <!-- This is needed for the virtual scroll to work properly -->
    <ion-list [virtualScroll]="friendsList">
      <ion-item *virtualItem="let friend">
        {{friend.name}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</div>
```